# Removing view when clicked, how to solve?

Tags: android, android-view

I noticed I was doing this in my code:

```
ResultButton = new Button( theActivity );
    ButtonUtils.setButtonValues( ... );

    ((ViewGroup) (theActivity).findViewById( android.R.id.content )).addView(   ResultButton );

    ResultButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         doStuff();


            ((ViewGroup) (getActivity()).findViewById( android.R.id.content )).removeView( ResultButton );

        }
    });
```

That seems clearly wrong, to remove itself inside its OnClickListener. But what is the right way to deal with these things. Since there is no main method in an Android program I cannot just set a flag and then have it deal with it later. 
You never really remove things? You just set them to invisible?

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `onClick` implementation, the argument that you didn't rename corresponds to the view that triggered the event, you can call the parent of said view and ask *it* to remove the said child view.

```
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          parentView.removeView(view);
```

To do this, rename `arg0` to `view`, and you should be fine

---

Another option, as you mention is to just toggle its visibility, calling the `setVisibility` method, to either `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` depending on wether you want to to keep taking the screen space it was taking when visible or be completely gone, but since you asked to *remove* the view, the first option should suffice.

Comment: Still seemd weird to do a removal from inside the thing you want to remove, even if it is the parent doing it.

Comment: You're not doing it from the "thing you want to remove", you're doing it from a listener which you declared inline (the onClickListener). But that listener could be implemented on your Activity if that made you feel like it's cleaner.